# I want to dynamically get values of all checked radio buttons in certain div on a click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to dynamically get values of all checked radio buttons in certain div on a click of button `.add`

```
<div class="item">

<title class="name">Espresso</title>

**<div class="option1">**

<fieldset>
<legend>Pick </legend>

<label for="radio-1" >Short</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio-1" class="radio-1" id="radio-1" 
value="Short">

<label for="radio-2">Long</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio-1" class="radio-1" id="radio-2" value="Long">
<hr>
<label for="radio-3">In big cup</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio-2" class="radio-1" id="radio-3" value="In big cup">

<label for="radio-4">Small cup</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio-2" class="radio-1" id="radio-4" 
value="Small cup">
</fieldset>

 </div>

 <hr>

 <button type="submit" class="add">+Add</button>

 <span class="price" value="4$">Price:<br>5$</span>

 </div>
```

And here is .js function that should get the values of radio buttons and append it to list, but im not getting any response.

```
$('.add').click (function(){
$(this).siblings("fieldset").children("input[type=radio]:checked")
.each(function () {
        var selectedOptions = $(this).parent().text();
        $(".orderOptions").last().append("<li> +selectedOption+ </li>");
    });
});
```

So whole process is:  .click (get values of all checked radio buttons from html div) and save it to the list.

Answer (score 0):

In your click event you wrote:

```
$(this).siblings("fieldset").children("input[type=radio]:checked")
```

this is wrong because `this` here is reference to the `button` not the `div` which you want to get the input inside it.

so you have to use the div itself :

```
$('#call1 fieldset input[type=radio]:checked')
```

then you can simply get the checked value by `this.value` and append it to any other div.

```js
$('.add').click (function(){
  $('#call1 fieldset input[type=radio]:checked')
    .each(function () {
     $('.orderOptions').append("<li>" +this.value+ "</li>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">

  <title class="name">Espresso</title>

  <div id="call1" class="option1">

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Pick </legend>

      <label for="radio-1" >Short</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio-1" class="radio-1" id="radio-1" 
             value="Short">

      <label for="radio-2">Long</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio-1" class="radio-1" id="radio-2" value="Long">
      <hr>
      <label for="radio-3">In big cup</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio-2" class="radio-1" id="radio-3" value="In big cup">

      <label for="radio-4">Small cup</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio-2" class="radio-1" id="radio-4" 
             value="Small cup">
    </fieldset>

  </div>

  <hr>

  <button type="submit" class="add">+Add</button>

  <span class="price" value="4$">Price:<br>5$</span>

</div>

<div class='orderOptions'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to address a fieldset relative to your "add" button, then you can use something like this:

```
$('.add').click (function(){
  ...
  $(this).siblings('div').find(':checked')
  ...
});
```

This works, because not your `<fieldset>` but the `<div class="option1">` is the sibling of the pressed button. Once you have found the right div with the fieldset within, the selector for the checked options can be simplified to `:checked`, since it searches within the `<div>` ("write less do more ...").

```js
$('.add').click (function(){
  $('.orderOptions').append('<hr><ul>'+
   $(this).siblings('div').find(':checked')
    .map((_,e)=>"<li>"+e.value+"</li>").get().join('')+'</ul>'
  )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">

  <title class="name">Espresso</title>

  <div id="call1" class="option1">

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Pick </legend>

      <label for="radio-1" >Short</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio-1" class="radio-1" id="radio-1" 
             value="Short">

      <label for="radio-2">Long</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio-1" class="radio-1" id="radio-2" value="Long">
      <hr>
      <label for="radio-3">In big cup</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio-2" class="radio-1" id="radio-3" value="In big cup">

      <label for="radio-4">Small cup</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio-2" class="radio-1" id="radio-4" 
             value="Small cup">
    </fieldset>

  </div>

  <hr>

  <button type="submit" class="add">+Add</button>

  <span class="price" value="4$">Price:<br>5$</span>

</div>

<div class='orderOptions'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
$(this).parent().children(".option1").children("fieldset").children("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function (index,element) {
    var selectedOptions = $(element).prev("label").text();
    $(".orderOptions").last().append("<li>" +selectedOptions+ "</li>");
});
```

Html

```
<div class="item">

<title class="name">Espresso</title>

**<div class="option1">**

<fieldset>
<legend>Pick </legend>

<label for="radio-1" >Short</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio-1" class="radio-1" id="radio-1" 
value="Short">

<label for="radio-2">Long</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio-1" class="radio-1" id="radio-2" value="Long">
<hr>
<label for="radio-3">In big cup</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio-2" class="radio-1" id="radio-3" value="In big cup">

<label for="radio-4">Small cup</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio-2" class="radio-1" id="radio-4" 
value="Small cup">
</fieldset>

 </div>

 <hr>

 <button type="submit" class="add">+Add</button>

 <span class="price" value="4$">Price:<br>5$</span>

 </div>
 <ul class="orderOptions">
 </ul>

 </div>
```